# How to store smaller images in Android?

Tags: android, image, camera

I am trying to develop an app with a camera. I have already successfully saved the image in the SD card, but the image will be sent to a server, so I need the image to be of a smaller size. The size that I am getting right now is 2.3 MB. Is there a way that I could make the image smaller?

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() 
{
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }
};
```

Comment: When you are going to upload it to server then you have an option to compress the bitmap file and it doesn't effect your quality of image also mBitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream).

Comment: deepak, where in the code will I put the `compress` part?

Comment: Where is the code where you are uploading your image to server .

Comment: I am storing the image first in the SD card, and then uploading to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Resize the image. Best results are achieved, by reducing resolution by a factor of 2. See this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/248432
2. Compress the image further (as Ravi Kumar already answered).

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your bitmap image(if it is stored in Bitmap) using this

**preview_bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);**